# How to configure htaccess-like files for configuring PHP when on shared hosting situations or FCGI?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am finding myself frequently needing to issue `php_value` directives to .htaccess, however with FCGI I'm simply stuck not being able to do this.

I thought the solution might be to use [htscanner](http://pecl.php.net/package/htscanner), however it seems a bit dated and problematic for some people in php 5+.

I also found [this snazzy little project](https://github.com/piannelli/htscanner-enhanced) ([htscanner-enhanced](https://github.com/piannelli/htscanner-enhanced)) that seems to perhaps offer a solution, but has not been updated recently… which always gives me pause and concern that perhaps it could become a headache I don't want to deal with down the road due to lack of maintenance.

Is there a preferred way of configuring php on a per site basis outside of these when the option of using `.htaccess` is not nonexistent?

Comment: PHP5.3 introduced [.user.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files, suitable for per-directory ini overrides.

Comment: We use htscanner-enhanced in production on all our servers, it works perfect, and I'm sure if you create a github issue about a problem, it will be fixed pretty fast.

But why should you update something if it just works? ;) Look at many linux tools, they haven't been updated for years.